# XamlParseException and user rights

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

We have installed a bran new windows 7 pro on a virtual server and installed Microsoft office. then we installed our small application. I'm at the second VM we make and still same issue rise. when running the application we get :

```
Application: ------.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(System.Exception, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader, Boolean, System.Object, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel, System.Uri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(System.IO.Stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(System.Uri, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
```

BUT that error doesn't happen for 2 user out of 8. This is not code issue as the application is on 1 computer and everyone connect with Remote Desktop to that computer to run the application. We can only have 1 remote session at a time. Remote session user are domain users and they are part of local administrator group on the machine. So we are wondering which right might be blocking the XAML loader ?

I'll add that the file is no running on the network it is totally local as `c:\program files (x86)\mysoftware\software.exe`. Not network redirection of drive either.

Comment: Any inner `Exception`?

Comment: i cannot know. it happen before my first window even show up. No try catch possible. I am only able to see it inside windows event log.

Comment: To clarify the error happen at loading `app.xaml` and doesn't trigger the `StartupUri`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was Domain rights. The other users were in different group as the other 2 accounts. Policies were changed and everything works now.